# C++ Why do I need two end of files?

Tags: c++, eof

Here is my code:

```
while (read(cin, record)) {
  //find length of longest name
  maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
  students.push_back(record);
}
```

and in a separate source

```
istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
   //read and store the students name and midterm and final exam grades
   is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;

   read_hw(is, s.homework);
   return is;
}

istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
   if (in) {
      //get rid of previous contents
      hw.clear();

      //read homework grades
      double x;
      while (in >> x)
         hw.push_back(x);

      //clear the stream so that input will work for the next student 
      in.clear();
   }
   return in;
}
```

Right so this works perfectly as expected/wanted except for the fact that two end of files are required to break the while loop. I had a hypothesis:

Calling in.clear(); at that time will clear the first EOF so it will end up having no effect.

But I don't think this can be the case as if I replace the second EOF with any letter or word, the loop will still break.

I've gone through it with Debug multiple times, and I can't think of anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I'm following a book (accelerated C++) which is quite old (2001) and this is the method they used. It's possible the method they used is outdated or simplified.

The example I'm writing gives no indication of how many pieces of homework there might be. Hence it appears to assume there are more pieces of homework until there is an input that can't be put in the double x.

Here is an example input that might be pasted in:

```
DBMA 24 66 16 89 68 57 
XORM 0 64 18 65 34 34 
DHKQ 8 65 32 77 79 99 
NZXI 86 49 7 43 57 17 
WGIN 8 85 99 69 41 58 
GMXD 15 47 25 18 53 45 
KSIQ 71 19 65 55 20 49 
NSRY 52 35 49 32 9 59 
RUMB 5 30 59 64 39 32 
ZGBM 95 62 67 71 50 76 
TSRQ 70 25 15 89 77 71 
FQDI 84 82 96 55 92 93 
VLOJ 75 25 11 51 43 83
```

And here an example output (note that the latter part involves parts of the program which I have not shown):

```
DBMA 24 66 16 89 68 57
XORM 0 64 18 65 34 34
DHKQ 8 65 32 77 79 99
NZXI 86 49 7 43 57 17
WGIN 8 85 99 69 41 58
GMXD 15 47 25 18 53 45
KSIQ 71 19 65 55 20 49
NSRY 52 35 49 32 9 59
RUMB 5 30 59 64 39 32
ZGBM 95 62 67 71 50 76
TSRQ 70 25 15 89 77 71
FQDI 84 82 96 55 92 93
VLOJ 75 25 11 51 43 83
^D
^D
Passing Students:
DBMA 69.8
DHKQ 74.6
FQDI 105
TSRQ 69
WGIN 74.8
ZGBM 85.6

Failing Students:
GMXD 44.8
KSIQ 53.6
NSRY 50.4
NZXI 57.4
RUMB 44.4
VLOJ 54
XORM 46

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Edit 2:
mcve?

Main: http://dumptext.com/4bfKcJL7

student_info.cpp: http://dumptext.com/AwgTkIYX

student_info.h: [ABOVE]/tamQmvbi    - need more rep apparently for more than 2 links

Comment: How do you know how many grades are in the stream? Either you need to store the number in the stream or exhaust it.

Comment: @tadman: Unlikely...

Comment: The reason you need two EOFs is because of that `clear`. You get the first one, clear it, then need a second to exit out your main loop. Like @NeilKirk suggests, you need a way to figure out how many homeworks there are. Once you have that, you can eliminate the clear.

Comment: Is this your code or did you inherit the code from somebody? Can you post sample input? The logic does not seem to be clearly thought out.

Comment: `in.clear();` does not clear out the stream.  `clear()` removes any error flags that have been set

Comment: @RSahu: This is code from an old book (accelerated c++) from 2001. At the end of the chapter you (the reader) are tasked with testing and making improvements. It's possible that the logic is deliberately perverse.

Comment: @Adam: Given the confusion about EOFs, it would be good to have this as an answer.  (Bonus points if it talks about how `^D` makes `read` return rather than actually “causing EOF”.)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong (and ignore EOF anyway).

- Using 'std::cin' interactive will never have an EOF (unless the user enters some terminal/console specific EOF key stroke).
- Having 'std::cin' in a pipeline (POSIX: pipe) or similar should have an EOF at some point of time.

You are checking for successful extractions in `read_hw`, but not in `read`. In addition you place `istream::clear()` in a random manner. Also, you need std::getline (or similar) to parse std::cin (interactive), reliable.

Comment: Let's say I input a Ctrl-D for a Linux command prompt.  What happens to the input?  Is it end of file?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 'Ctrl-D' in a Linux terminal is an EOF, but it is an implementation detail of  the terminal and another thing to worry about. Thanks.

Comment: As explained in my edits ^D is used as an EOF, I get that it might not be the best way (maybe detect the word 'done' or something) but currently this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Each line has the same number of tokens.

After

```
is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;
```

each line is left with four more tokens. You can change `read_hw` to take advantage of that information:

```
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
   //get rid of previous contents
   hw.clear();

   for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
   {
      double x;
      if (in >> x)
      {
         hw.push_back(x);
      }
      else
      {
         // Problem.
         // Return prematurely.
         return in;
      }
   }

   return in;
}
```

If you cannot depend on the number of homework scores to be fixed, you can read the rest of the line using `std::getline()` and then use `std::istringstream` to process the rest of the line.

```
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
   //get rid of previous contents
   hw.clear();

   // Read the rest of the line
   std::string line;
   std::getline(in, line);

   // If there was an error in reading the rest of the line, return
   if ( !in )
   {
      return in;
   }

   // Extract the numbers from the line using an istringstream
   std::istringstream str(line);

   double x;
   while (str >> x)
   {
      hw.push_back(x);
   }

   return in;
}
```

Comment: From the data I used you would be right (though it would 4 not 3 tokens), but this is my just completely made up data (nothing to do with the book). But what teacher would give some students some number of homework and some students another number of homework?

Comment: I tried the second suggestion and it runs, but there is still the exact same ^d ^d problem :(

Comment: @EdwardKotarski, it will so much easier if you can please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I've done an MCVE? Took out the unnecessary code atleast.